# Webcam not displaying even though it is detected - Kubuntu 20.04

Tags: drivers, webcam, 20.04

I have recently updated my Kubuntu from 18.04 to 20.04. In the previous version, everything seemed to work well. After the upgrade, every time I try to use the webcam the light turns on but no output is displayed. I have try checking the camera with cheese, Skype and VLC.

The outputs from `lsusb` are the following:

```
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 058f:a014 Alcor Micro Corp. Asus Integrated Webcam
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 0cf3:3005 Qualcomm Atheros Communications AR3011 Bluetooth
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

I have a dual boot machine and the camera works just fine in Windows. The output from `ls -ltr /dev/video*` are the following:

```
crw-rw----+ 1 root video 81, 1 Apr 29 11:10 /dev/video1
crw-rw----+ 1 root video 81, 0 Apr 29 11:10 /dev/video0
```

I know that more people have this problem, so I hope we can get some answers soon. Thank you.